# How to force a generic function only accepts exactly one parameter in typescript with complex definitions?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm creating a generator function that will decorate supplied function for my custom npm package so it have to works well with "noImplicitAny" for javascript projects that using type checking. I found a way to restrict the supplied function to the decorator. But somehow it only can restrict the parameter type and the return type, but not the "how much arguments" that should be provided to the function.

I want the supplied function only accepts exactly one parameter.

My index.ts

```js
type Constraints<C> = C extends
    | Function
    | PropertyDescriptor
    | Document
    | Omit<RegExp, "lastIndex">
    | void
    | never
    ? never
    : C;

type Parameter<T extends (arg: any) => any> = T extends (args: infer P) => any
    ? P
    : never;

interface SupplierFunction<T extends (...args: any) => any> {
    (arg0: Constraints<Parameter<T>>): Parameter<T> extends undefined
        ? never
        : Constraints<ReturnType<T>>;
    (...arg0: Constraints<Parameter<T>[]>): Parameter<T> extends undefined
        ? never
        : Constraints<ReturnType<T>>;
}

export default function decorateFunction<F extends SupplierFunction<F>>(fn: F) {
    return async (payload: Constraints<Parameter<F>>) => {
        const result: Constraints<ReturnType<F>> = await new Promise((resolve) => {
                resolve(fn(payload));
        });
        return result;
    };
}
```

Most of test cases works, but not for argument count

main.ts

```js
/**
 * Initializing function
 */
 
// Should OK
const f1 = decorateFunction((payload) => {
    return 2;
});
const f2 = decorateFunction((payload: string) => {
    return false;
});
const f3 = decorateFunction(({ payload }) => {
    return (1 + 2).toString();
});
const f4 = decorateFunction(({ payload }: { payload: boolean }) => {
    return null;
});

// Should Error
const e1 = decorateFunction();
const e2 = decorateFunction(() => {});
const e3 = decorateFunction("");
const e4 = decorateFunction(() => true); // not showing error, it should accept exactly one param
const e5 = decorateFunction((payload) => {});
const e6 = decorateFunction((payload1, payload2) => false); // the error should be the count of parameter, should only accept exactly one

/**
 * Reusing the function
 */

// Should OK
const r1 = f1("anything"); // Promise<number>
const r2 = f2("string"); // Promise<boolean>
const r3 = f3({ payload: "anything" }); // Promise<string>
const r4 = f4({ payload: true }); // Promise<null>

// Should Error
const re1 = f1("any").then((e) => e.charAt(1));
const re2 = f2(1);
const re3 = f3("parameter should be object");
const re4 = f4({ nothing: "property invalid" });
```

You can check [this playground](https://tsplay.dev/mAxzPN) for complete example

Comment: If you want to restrict to a single parameter, why are you explicitly allowing arbitrary number of parameters like `(...arg0: Constraints<Parameter<T>[]>): ⋯`?  Maybe I just don't understand what you're asking for?  Very confused.

Comment: Some of the code in your question is confusing and unmotivated and should be [edit]ed to clarify. For example ① any union with `never` will absorb the `never`, so your `Constraints<T>` can be simplified.  Indeed the whole thing could be simplified to `Exclude<Function | PropertyDescriptor | ⋯, C>`. ② What's `Omit<RegExp, "lastIndex">`? Is that a supertype of `RegExp` you care about? Why? ③ Why turn off `--noImplicitAny`? Could you just turn it on and then annotate things as necessary? Uncommon compiler configs are harder to deal with

Comment: noImplicityAny should be turned off because it should also works with implicitany types inside javascript projects

Comment: this overloading function `(...arg0: Constraints<Parameter<T>[]>): ⋯` can make implicit any works well for the function

Comment: I don't think I'll be able to help much, sorry, I just don't get the point of at least half of the code you've got here.  Keep in mind that [functions of fewer parameters are intentionally assignable to functions of more parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters) so anything you do to reject `()=>{}` but accept `(arg)=>{}` will be fighting against the TS type system for questionable benefit (see that link for reasoning).  Anyway I think I'll disengage now. Good luck!